# Disabling playlist song hover info in Amarok2?

Tags: linux, amarok

Anyone know how to disable this annoying hover info in new amarok 2.4? I browsed through all the options (not that there is much of them), but couldn't find how to turn that feature off... It's getting in the way when hovering over songs with your mouse and really is not necessary

thank you